# Random commas appear in array ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, random

I am trying to create this memory game in ReactJS and I have made an array in which I add 4 random numbers. Now everytime I press play game I need to fill the array with 4 random numbers 0 to 3 but I keep getting random commas that come out of nowhere in the array. I am quite new to React so any help is appreciated.

I have tried different methods of filling up the array but the commas still appear. P.S: keepArray was initialized just before the for loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
      keepArray = [...keepArray + rand]
      console.log(keepArray)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution:

Replace:

`keepArray = [...keepArray + rand]`

with:

`keepArray = [...keepArray, rand]`

---

#### Explanation:

The spread operator (`...`) is literally "spreading" your array, that's why you need commas. The example bellow may help to visualize it:

```
// Let's start with a simple array:
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];

// Now, we add another element to it using spread:
var updatedArray = [...myArray, 4];

// Here, ...myArray is translated to [1, 2, 3]
// That means that the above could be read as:
var updatedArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

---

For an extra explanation about the "+" behavior, see Pavan Bahuguni answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to add a better explanation. Let me know if that makes sense :)

Comment: I get it now. Awesome explanation thanks! I topvote in 5 min :)

Comment: Glad to know it helped! Consider accepting it as the right answer if that solved your problem. And good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

The above answer does fix the problem, but the real reason for the behaviour is as follows.

The + operator is overloaded to serve the purposes of both number addition and string concatenation. When + receives an object (including array in your case) for either operand, it first calls the ToPrimitive abstract operation on the value, which then calls the [[DefaultValue]] algorithm with a context hint of number. Which intern calls toString method on the array.

```
var val = [1,2,3] + 1;
console.log(val); // "1,2,31"
```

And then you are trying to spread that string in an array like so,

```
var arr = [...val];
console.log(arr); // ["1", ",", "2", ",", "3", "1"]
```

this is the actual reason why you are seeing those commas.

Comment: Thank you for that more in-depth explanation! it sure helps

Comment: Great explanation! I will update with a reference to your answer.